# How good are modern recommender engines?

Tags: recommendation-engine

What quality of recommendation must a new recommender system have in order to be competitive?

By "quality of recommendation" I mean following. Let's say, the recommender system presented the user X items. Thereafter I ask him, how many of them he or she actually liked (may buy) and it turns out he liked Y of them. Quality of recommendation is Y/X (best possible value is 1, which means that the user liked all recommended items).

What quality of recommendation do

1. average and
2. best

recommender systems have approximately?

**Update 1:** [Here](http://de.slideshare.net/xamat/recommender-systems-machine-learning-summer-school-2014-cmu) (page 64) the authors write that in 2007 Netflix prize top 2 algorithms achieved RMSE of 0.8914 and 0.8990, respectively.

The definition of RMSE can be found on page 63, but I don't get what it means.

Comment: Not like what you think as binary, the predicted score in netflix competition are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (the 5-star rating used in netfix). Then it makes sense to use RMSE as the evaluation metric.

Comment: @greeness Is there a way to interpret this metrics in an accessible (non-mathematical) way? What does it mean, if an algorithm has RMSE of 0? What does it mean, if it has RMSE of 1?

Comment: RMSE=0 means every predicted score is an exact match of the golden. Suppose you have three movies whose golden scores are r1=2, r2=3, r3=5 respectively. If your prediction are exactly p1=2, p2=3, p3=5 (`r` for golden rating, `p` for prediction), you get an RMSE score of 0. If your prediction is however, p1=1, p2=4, p3=4, you get total squared error 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 3, RMSE = sqrt(3/3) = 1. So if on average, each rating is deviating from the golden by 1, you get RMSE error of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually asking quite an interesting question. There is still a lively debate going on in the academic community about a) what a "good" recommendation even means, and b) the metrics to use for prediction accuracy, and other evaluation measures.

You asked:

> What quality of recommendation do average and best recommender systems have approximately?

The answer is - it depends on a lot of different things. The short answer is there is no real agreed "average" or "best" for recommender systems in general, but you may find benchmarks for specific recommender systems - such as movie recommender systems.

To help give you a bit more background:

Root Mean Squared Error is used as a measure of prediction accuracy. I.e. Given a set of items (bread, milk, coffee, orange juice) how well can the system predict my ratings for these items, or how well it can predict that i will buy these items.

You can use the RMSE when you have a set of predicted ratings for a User for a set of Items, AND you also have their actual ratings for those items. You would typically use RMSE in an "offline" experiment with your real dataset. During this process you would "hide" some of the real ratings and see if the system can predict the hidden ratings. The "error" part of RMSE is the difference between the predicted rating and the actual rating. Each error is then squared first then the average of these errors across the set of items for that user is take (the mean part), then the square root is taken (the root part of the name). Because RMSE squares the error first it disproportionally penalises large errors, compared with other accuracy metrics such as Mean Absolute Error (MAE).

There is a lot more to making a good recommendation than just making accurate predictions. This is why there is not a standard/average number to go by. There are a range of different metrics to use for accuracy, and then accuracy is only one small part of measuring how effective a recommender system is, and the other parts all have multiple metrics that can be used too! It also depends on the item you are recommending. Recommending someone to go on a date with, is hardly the same as recommending what food to buy online. I have seen scores for movie recommenders at 0.8+ RMSE and scores for recommending jobs at 0.2+ RMSE.

I recommend reading the below papers if you are wanting to get a better (no mathematical) appreciation into the complexities of evaluating recommender systems:

Herlocker, Konstan, Terveen, Diedl - "Evaluating Collaborative Filtering Recommender Systems" (2004) - is a good paper to start to appreciate the different approaches that can be used to evaluate RS performance.

Another good paper is McNee, Riedl and Konstan - "Accuracy is Not Always Good: How accuracy metrics have hurt recommender systems" (2006)